# Convert function to Live/On (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me converting this function to a live/on version for jQuery 1.8.3?

We load videos dynamically from a database and append it to HTML on the page. 
This piece of code show more/less of the text info below the videos. (Like on YT.)

Everyting I tried so far didn't make this function work in the append-content.

```
$(".showmore").toggle(function(){
    $(this).text("- show less -").siblings(".complete").show();    
}, function(){
    $(this).text("- read more -").siblings(".complete").hide();    
});
```

Comment: you are missing a event binding, this is the same in jquery 1.8.3

Comment: FYI: The [`.toggle()` event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: @voigtan: This *is* an event binding.  He want to delegate the event.

Comment: Thanks guys! I missed that apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That version of `toggle()` was removed, but you can toggle the text with a callback, and the visiblity with the remaining version of `toggle()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.showmore', function() {
    $(this).text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt == '- show less -' ? '- read more -' : '- show less -';
    }).siblings('.complete').toggle();
});
```